# Почему не отправляется изображение move_uploaded_file? PHP , MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, веб-программирование

есть такой код.

```
$uposter = '/img/films/'. time() . $_FILES['urlposter']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['urlposter']['tmp_name'], '../cvyt.ru/img/films/', $uposter);
```

Переменная **$uposter** это обычный  input с типом "file" и именем **'urlposter'**.

Сама форма `<form action="morers.php" class="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Почему не передаётся картинка при нажатии на кнопку с типом **submit**?

---

Примечание: При нажатии на кнопку должна отправиться картинка в **img/films** и путь записываться в mysql. Путь уже записывается, но картинка не передаётся.

Comment: Функция `move_uploaded_file` принимает 2 аргумента, а у тебя три. Почему?

Comment: @u_mulder, понял, изменяю

Comment: @u_mulder, оставил `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['urlposter']['tmp_name'], $uposter);` , не помогает

Comment: Путь `'/img/films/'` в переменной uposter считается __от корня__ системы. Я сомневаюсь что в корне системы есть папка `img`. Поэтому тебе надо скорректировать путь.

Comment: @u_mulder, а как скорректировать?

Comment: @u_mulder, есть на хостинге папка cvyt.ru, в ней img, затем films

Comment: Так чтобы он указывал на существующую директорию. Либо пиши от корня системы. Либо может у тебя в приложении есть какая-то константа типа DOCUMENT_ROOT. Можно глянуть в `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` и плясать от нее.

Comment: Либо если папка `img` лежит в той же директории что и php-скрипт, то можно указать путь без слеша: `$uposter = 'img/films/' ...`

Comment: @u_mulder, может быть проблема в том что я пытаюсь с другого сайта перенести изображение на другой сайт? Т.е на хостинге у меня 2 сайта и я хочу перенести с одного, на другой, т.е CVYT. DOCUMENT_ROOT'a нету

Comment: @u_mulder, как передать файл на другой сайт этим же путём? move uploaded? в img, только другой сайт, с другими img

Comment: @inorviga тебе обычный mc в помощь и переноси что угодно и куда угодно в пределах сервера, а если сильно захотеть, то и на другой сервер.